# Accessing state in an IO-Monad

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I'm trying to access a state of a State Monad inside an IO action.

More specifically: I'm trying to write a state-dependent signal handler using `installHandler`from [System.Posix.Signals](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Signals.html) which requires `IO`, however, I'd like to do different actions and change the state from inside the handler. I took a look at [unliftio](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio), but I read that State-Monads shouldn't be unlifted.

Is this possible? I'm more looking for an explanation than for a "copy-paste" solution. If unlifting State inside IO doesn't work, what would a solution look like, for when one wants to do some state-aware processing inside IO?

Comment: If everything fails, you can use `IORef`s inside IO.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! There's another approach I'll probably use that doesn't rely on IO, but I still wanted to know why this won't work

Comment: I can't see another safe way to send data from a signal handler to the rest of the program. Handling signals can't be done outside IO, AFAIK. In a State monad, `do x <- get ; y <- get ; return (x==y)` should be equivalent to `return True`, since you can't modify the state in the middle. This differs from IO and IORefs, since there we have threads / signal handlers that can modify an IORef between two reads. Perhaps you have seen an alternative I do not know about?

Comment: I do not know of an alternative, I just don't understand why we shouldn't unlift state in IO, that's it. But thanks for mentioning IORef, I didn't know about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A value of type `State a b` does not contain a state. It is just an encapsulated function that can provide a resulting state and a result if you pass it a starting state (using the `runState` function. There is no way to access an intermediate (or "current") state from the outside of this function. This is what makes the `State` Monad "pure".

You seem to intend to have a handler, that does not always behave the same (even if invoked with the same parameters), but depends on an outside state. This kind of behaviour is "impure", and *cannot* be achieved by using only pure means. So what you need in this case is something that encapsulates the impureness in a way that you can access a "current value" of some state from the handler, without the current value itself getting passed into the handler.

As you already know from the comments, the go-to tool to provide access to mutable state to an `IO` action is using an `IORef`. IORefs work, because the Haskell runtime (traditionally, before multithreading at least) serializes `IO` actions. So the concept of the "current value" always makes sense. After every IO action, the value pointed to by every IORef is fixed. The order IO actions happen is also fixed, as it needs to be the order you chain them inside `do` blocks or using the `>>=` operators. Handling of Signals is performed by the Haskell runtime in a deterministic way, kind of like everytime you chain two IO actions, the runtime checks for pending signals, and invokes the corresponding handler.

In case you want to write code that manipulates data in an imperative way (where you can have a lot of variables, and even arrays where you update sinlge elements), you could write your code as I/O action and use `IORef` and `IOArray` for it, but there is a special "lite" version of IO that just supports mutable state in the same way as I/O without being able to interact with the environment. The shared state needs to be created, read and written from inside the same "capsule" of this special IO lite, so that running the whole action does not interact with outside state, but just with its internal state - the capsule as a whole is thus pure, even if single statements inside the capsule can be considered impure. The name of this lite version of IO is called `ST`, which is short for "state thread".

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It's clearer now!